# Assign css class in the injected html in Angular 7

Tags: css, angular, angular7

I want to assign css class based on some calculation. This is my component class:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-render-json',
  template: `<div [innerHtml]="html | safeHtml"></div>`,
  styleUrls: ['./render-json.component.css'] , encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom
})

export class RenderJsonComponent {
  @Input() myJson: any;
  html = ``;
  static levelDeep = 1
  
  ngOnInit() {
    this.renderJson(this.myJson)
  }
  
  renderJson(obj) {
    RenderJsonComponent.levelDeep = RenderJsonComponent.levelDeep + 1
  for(var key in obj) {
      if(key != 'id') {
        this.html = this.html + `<div class="col-md-${RenderJsonComponent.levelDeep}  col-md-offset-${RenderJsonComponent.levelDeep}">${obj[key]}</div>`
        // This does not work but I want to do something like this
      }
  }
 }
}
```

Basically, I need to render some JSON in a GRID style through bootstrap using offset classes but this does not work somehow. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the output of  `this.html` in console?

Comment: When you add a tag to a question, it shows the tag information. The tag information for `angularjs` specifically notes that it should not be used for Angular >= 2.

Comment: the html gets rendered but the classes are not applied to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-render-json',
  template: `<div [innerHtml]="safeHtml"></div><div *ngFor="jsonElements as element" class="element.class">element.obj</div>`,
  styleUrls: ['./render-json.component.css'] , encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom
})

export class RenderJsonComponent {
  @Input() myJson: any;
  myLevelDeep = 1;
  jsonElements = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.renderJson(this.myJson)
  }

  renderJson(obj) {
    this.myLevelDeep = RenderJsonComponent.levelDeep + 1
        for(var key in obj) {
      if(key != 'id') {
        jsonElements.push({class:"col-md-" + this.myLevelDeep + " col-md-offset-" + this.myLevelDeep, obj: obj[key]});
      }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There are a couple of problems with the answer. Firstly it will not inject html object since our `html` object is empty and not being appended by any div. I tried your approach but nothing gets printed with any json. Could you please provide a pluner for fiddle answer in order to demo that this answer is correct with some sample 5-6 level deep nested json.

Comment: Yes, this is not appending several elements, this is just hiding or showing one element. I didn't got this in the first view. I will refactor the example.